# Change the sequence of rows in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have dataset with multiple values for each `ID`, and I would like to rearrange the sequence of rows based on a sequence of IDs.

Sample data

```
ID     Value1 Value2 Value3
279556 123    123ABC 123ABCXYZ
279557 456    456DEF 456DEFXYZ
280484 789    789HIJ 789HIJXYZ
280485 111    111KLM 111KLMXYZ
```

Desired sequence

```
ID     Value1 Value2 Value3
279557 456    456DEF 456DEFXYZ
280485 111    111KLM 111KLMXYZ
279556 123    123ABC 123ABCXYZ
280484 789    789HIJ 789HIJXYZ
```

I tried the following code but the order still remains the same.

How can I fix this?

```
library(dplyr)

# Rearrange data 
Sequence = c("279557", "280485", "279556", "280484") 

df = df%>%
  mutate(category =  factor(ID, levels = Sequence)) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

Comment: You are `arrange`ing by 'ID' and not by `category` where `category` is the modified 'ID'

Comment: @akrun, thank you, silly silly mistakes I make.